# Specifying a person in a queue

Tags: phrase-usage, phrase-request, phrase-choice

I cannot find out how can I specify a person in a queue, his turn.

I've produced just the sentences below:

`the student whose turn came`

`the student who has the current turn`

I wonder that which one is true and is there a better way?

Comment: The *first/second/third/etc.* student in line, maybe?  Or the student *at the head of the line*?  I'm not sure if either of those is what you want, exactly.  Sorry, I'm American; we tend to say *line* instead of *queue* but I'm not sure if it refers to what you're thinking of!

Comment: How would the phrase be used? Are we referring to a student still waiting, or not? (in my mind, a student being served is no longer in the queue at all)

Comment: @stangdon,  I meant the student the first in a line. And I guess your proposal is what I search for. (the student at the head of the line) - So thank you a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your sentences do get the point across, but they both seem a bit clunky to me. Depending on how the phrase is used in context, something like this might work...

> the student currently being seen (or *served* or *helped*)
>
> the student at the front of the queue
>
> the first in the queue

I'll note that I'm an American English speaker, and we use the word *line* where others use *queue*, so it's possible I am misusing *queue* somewhat.

Comment: Queue is BrE. You aren't misusing it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. ı want to specify a student who is at the front of the queue and "would be served".